# Chrome developer is hiding status and response

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a request that fails with the 500 status and a trivial body. See the Postman screenshot:

[image: postman]

This same request in Chrome (latest) developer tools - the network tab:

[image]

and response:

[image: response]

How can I get the real response body and status?